# Push dynamic value to digitalData layer in adobe analytics

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I have followed the adobe analytics documentation to set adobe launcher on my website.

Setting static values in the digitalData layer in head tag is sending the data to adobe server. But when I try to add the values dynamically (when dom has finished loading), and push to the server, nothing is being sent.

This the object below is the equivalent for the variable.

```
eVar0 = digitalData.pageData.channel
```

In the head tag:

```
  <script>
    digitalData = {};
  </script

  <script>(function(g,b,d,f){(function(a,c,d){if(a){var e=b.createElement("style"); e.id =c;e.innerHTML=d;a.appendChild(e)}})(b.getElementsByTagName("head")
  [0],"at-body-style",d);setTimeout(function(){var a=b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];if(a){var c=b.getElementById("at-body-style");c&&a.removeChild
  (c)}},f)})(window,document,"body {opacity: 0 !important}",3E3);
  </script>

  <script src="https://assets.adobedtm.com/e6bd1902389a/8c29baadc24f/launch-c0eade28c3b0-development.min.js" async></script>
```

In the js loaded in the body:

```
digitalData.pageData = {"pagename" : page_name_var};
s.tl();
```

To be noted that in the console, the dynamic values are present in the digitaData layer object.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what event you'd like the data to transmit with, but chances are good that you'll need to defer the PageLoad event until after your dynamic values are populated in the dataLayer. If the PageLoad event happens before the dynamic value has been updated, there won't be anything for Launch to grab.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was sending the data on pageview. I have found a way to make it work by appending the launch script when the page is ready and populating the dynamic values in the data layer before it is done.